# How to use TIdHTTPServer with visual components?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-11-alexandria

I have an app that uses `TIdHTTPServer` to run a simple HTTP server on port 80. I'm using the `OnCommandGet` event to get commands and return data using `TClientDataSet`.

It works, but the problem is, this same app has visual components attached to the `TClientDataSet`, like `TDBGrid`.

And what is happening is, when `OnCommandGet` changes `TClientDataSet.CommandText`, the `TDBGrid` needs to be updated and then weird things start to happen: the `TDBGrid` starts to have glitches, the Form itself starts to behave strangely. After this happens, the only fix is to restart the application.

I know that probably this is because some thread is messing with visual components and I know I should avoid this by synchronizing the thread, but I don't know how to do this using `TIdHTTPServer`.

Any help would be very appreciated, I'm having to restart my app several times during the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that probably this is because some thread is messing with visual components

Correct. `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component, its `OnCommand...` events are fired in worker threads, so you must synchronize with the main UI thread when touching UI components.

> I know I should avoid this by synchronizing the thread, but I don't know how to do this using `TIdHTTPServer`.

You synchronize with the main UI thread like with any other worker thread - by using the `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()` method, or Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class.  For example:

```
procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequeestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  ...
  TThread.Synchonize(nil, // or TThread.Queue()...
    procedure
    begin
      ...
      ClientDataSet1.CommandText := ...;
      ...
    end
  );
  ...
end;
```

The alternative is to simply not touch the `TClientDataSet` in the `OnCommandGet` event at all.  Give the thread its own dedicated connection to the database and use local components to query/update the data.  Have the main thread use its own database connection when hooking up the `TDGBrid`.